# How to cynthonize numpy arrays to speed up performance?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, cython

I want to speed up the outside for loops (not shared cause its huge) outside this function `isSubsetQuick` that iterates inside a for loop.

The goal is to convert python numpy arrays into cython numpy arrays tobe able to use the numpy functions as `np.isin`, and to speed up the data assignation inside those not shared for loops.

How to cynthonize the arrays and function to optimize and speed up the for loop and the function as well?

(This is just a part of the code, cause there are more for loops outside this with array data assignation and it's slow, that's why I want to optimize).

```
def isSubsetquick(arr_3d: np.ndarray, arr_1d: np.ndarray, limit_elemets: int):

    common_elements = np.isin(arr_3d, arr_1d[:limit_elemets])
    quantity_common_elements = np.sum(common_elements, axis=-1)

    counter = np.count_nonzero(quantity_common_elements == limit_elemets)

    return counter 


array_3 = np.array([[[1, 2, 3, 7], [4, 5, 6, 8]], [[7, 8, 9, 4], [10, 11, 12, 5]]])
array_1 = np.array([1, 2, 6])

cdef int limit=3
cdef int size= 100000
cdef int result

#for x in range (size):
    print(result = isSubsetquick(array_3, array_1, limit))
```

Comment: The numpy routines are already in compiled C and Fortran.  Your Python plumbing here represents an insignificant part of your run time, and that's all Cython is going to help.

Comment: This is just a part of the code, there are more for loops outside this. I want to use cython to speed up the outside loops and arrays data assignation.

Comment: "cynthonize numpy arrays to speed up performance" This is a wrong assumption. The only way to speed up this code is to write a code that do not use Numpy and does the samething more efficiently than Numpy. While this is certainly possible, this is not easy : we have already strongly optimized `np.count_nonzero` and `np.sum` should be very fast already (nearly optimal for integers with the last version of Numpy). IDK for `np.isin`. Which part is supposed to be the slowest? How long are each function call? Do you plan to call the function with such very small arrays in a real-world code?

Comment: The thing is that the slow part of the code is huge and I am just sharing this part cause the thing I really want to speed up is the outside for loops with numpy arrays but for cython. I know numpy is fast that why I want to use cynthonized numpy arrays to access the numpy functions.

Comment: I know it seems like we're being stubborn, but it's the painful voice of experience. ;)  Clearly, you can cythonize loops like that, but unless you have done some instrumentation to know where you're spending your time, it's a waste.  If 85% of your time is spent inside numpy, then NOTHING YOU DO with the rest of the code can ever improve things more than 15%.  (Credit Amdahl's Law.)

Comment: This is the only numpy thing and its fast, the slow part is the for loops.

Comment: 1) Please do `line_profile`ing.  2) Then could you give example of such slow part, with results of line_profiling? I am pretty sure its not outside for loops that are causing the slow down but some code "around" it.

Comment: IS your x iterating through array 1 or 3?

Comment: I solved it with memory view cython arrays. Thank you all.